# Красива чи гарна? Як правильно сказати про привабливість дiвчини?

Tags: вживання-слів

Вітаю. 
Підкажіть, будь ласка, як більш грамотно сказати дівчині про її красу? Красива чи гарна?

Answer (score 3):

Сучасний [словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44821&page=1419) подає такі статті:

> **КРАСИ́ВИЙ**, а, е. Те саме, що га́рний
>
> Високий, красивий, він прямо поступив у двір(Панас Мирний)
>
> **ГА́РНИЙ**, а, е, вищ. ст. кра́щий і лі́пший, рідко гарні́ший, а, е.
>
> Який має привабливу зовнішність, привабливі риси обличчя; вродливий.
>
> Тільки тепер усі побачили, який він був гарний, стрункий, широкогрудий – справжній красень(О. Гончар);
>
> Цей лейтенант гарний на вроду і зовсім юний. Йому років двадцять (Є. Доломан).

Отже, на означення привабливості можна використовувати прикметники і **гарна**, і **красива**.

Answer (score 2):

### Красуня, Гарнюня

[**Краса**](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0) — це абстрактна категорія сприйняття людини на позначення сукупності якостей і властивостей об'єкта, які викликають суб'єктивне відчуття приємності у спостерігача.

Краса - це відносне поняття, яке може бути визначене як міра відповідності об'єкта до встановлених вимог або через порівняння окремих його характеристик з еталоном.

**[Врода (урода)](http://sum.in.ua/s/vroda)** — це синонім до *Краса* на позначення фізичної привабливості людини.

Коли кажуть "гарна дівчина" або "гарна дружина" насамперед, мають на увазі характер та особистісні якості людини.

Коли кажуть "вродлива дівчина", мають на увазі саме привабливу зовнішність.

Answer (score 0):

Вродлива дівчина, гарна дівчина, красуня, красунечка;
Ставний парубок, красень, богатир, козак, лицар.

Comment: Те саме, що й [тут](/a/6885). (Можливо, це було помилкове рішення засновників сайту, але ми намагалися зробити одним із принципів цього сайту доказовість/перевірюваність.) Але в будь-якому разі дуже дякую за участь!

Answer (score -1):

Слово "[Красиво](http://sum.in.ua/s/krasyvo)" не звучить в Українськоій мові. А чому? Тому що було додане до Української мови за часів СССР, коли намагалися викоринити Український народ усіма можливими способоми. Якщо ви хочете щоб ваша мова лилася як пісня, використовуйти: Гарна!

```
КРАСИ́ВО. Присл. до красивий. В його хаті.. переставляла [Христя] .. 
всяку всячину, щоб вона якнайкрасивіше стояла, найпоказніше видавала 
(Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 223); Його обличчя з високим і чистим чолом, 
трохи випнутими вилицями і красиво окресленими губами було привабливим  
(Вадим Собко, Скеля.., 1961, 8).
```

Comment: З одного боку, мені дуже імпонує Ваша позиція. Але з іншого: [Панас Мирний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Панас_Мирний) (на якого посилаєтеся зокрема й Ви) жив до СРСР. (А ще були Іван Котляревський, Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, Тарас Шевченко, Олекса Стороженко, Іван Нечуй-Левицький, Олександр Кониський, Леся Українка, Марко Кропивницький і інші, і вони теж вживали це слово.)

Comment: Хоча, правду кажучи, у часи СРСР, здається, відносна популярність цього слова доволі зросла: https://imgur.com/78DgcRi. (Але при цьому, здається, існувало воно завжди.)

Comment: @Sasha Дуже цікавий ресурс! Дякую. Мабудь якось ігнорував це слово в творах Шевченка, або тепер став більше уважнішим до таких слів. Але я всеж таки казав не тільки про те що воно не наше, але ще й за те як звучить слово Красивий в нашій мові.

Comment: Ну, як звучить — це доволі суб'єктивно. Хоча з іншого боку, якщо ми вже маємо _гарний_, _красний_ тощо, то, може, і без слова _красивий_ можна було б обійтися. (Але ми маємо і однокорінні слова: _краса_, _красний_, _прикрашати_ тощо — і слова зі схожими суфіксами: _сміливий_, _хтивий_ тощо).